# Как вызвать событие клик на сайте vk

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, хотел давно написать скрипт который будет поздравлять друзей с днем рождения. Но как заставить скрипт кликать по ссылка данной соц сети, обычный метод click() не работает. Я пишу с js с помощью jquery.

Comment: НЕЛЬЗЯ запустить JS на стороннем ресурсе, если конечно вы не собираетесь взламывать VK ))

Comment: Почитайте про Selenium Web Driver

Comment: Скрипт будет работать на стороне клиента.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 0):

> обычный метод click() не работает

А как вы делаете? Вообще-то должно работать если данный элемент уже построен в DOM на данный момент и если он правильно получается (`getElementsBy***`), экспериментировать следует сперва вручную в консоли DevTools в браузере, jQuery для такого рода задач лучше "выкинуть" и использовать нативный JS, по крайней мере до тех пор, как научитесь анализировать ее код и понимать, что "скрывается" за этим click().
Затем, когда сам скрипт готов, для его автоматизации есть разные пути - написать расширение к браузеру, использовать Selenium, Phantom.js.
Также есть альтернативный вариант, на другом архитектурном уровне: изучить HTTP, освоить снифферы вроде Fiddler, Wireshark, и на каком-либо ЯП реализовать отправку HTTP-запросов, таких же, как отправляет AJAX на странице VK, перехваченный вами сниффером.

Comment: Я использую расширение Tampermonkey, который позволяет запускать скрипты, как на старых операх. Если взять типичных блог, то там событие click() работает, и другие тоже, а на крутых проектах, скорее защита стоит. От на кнопку в вк повесили 3 класса, я по порядку перебрал каждый $(".class").click(); но нечего не происходит. Скрипт не может нажать.

Comment: @Sergiyss Нет никакого смысла пробовать три класса: элемент или получен, или получен, или получен не тот, так что если получен и именно тот, то и не нужно ничего больше пробовать в плане получения. Зато нужно прочитать мой ответ и попробовать сделать, как написал. Вы, наверное, не знаете, но ценные указания дают не просто так, а для того, чтобы их соблюдали.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("VideoCard__action VideoCard__action--delete")
        .forEach(function(el){el.click();});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]